# Как можно стереть (удалить) лишние графики в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.7

После нахождения точки пересечения двух прямых требуется оставить только оси координат и полученную точку. Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fig = plt.figure()
#ls = fig.add_subplot(111)

fig, ls = plt.subplots()

p,q,v,k,b1=2,4,3,4,6

X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.05)
Y = k*X
plt.plot(X,Y)

ls.plot(q,0)
ls.scatter(q, 0, color='orange', marker='o')
ls.text(q, 0.3, "Q", horizontalalignment="center")

ls.plot(p,0)
ls.scatter(p, 0, color='orange', marker='o')
ls.text(p, 0.3, "P", horizontalalignment="center")

ls.plot(-v,0)
ls.scatter(-v, 0, color='orange', marker='o')
ls.text(-v, 0.8, "V", horizontalalignment="center")

xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax=-10,10,-10,10
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)

ls.plot(0.0,b1)
ls.scatter(0.0, b1, color='blue', marker='o')
ls.text(0.8, b1, "B1", horizontalalignment="center")

l1 = b1*x+b1*v - v*y
vb = ls.contour(x,y, l1, [0], colors='red')

l2 = -b1*X/p + b1
ls.plot(X,l2)

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(Y - l2))).flatten()
plt.plot(X[idx], Y[idx], 'ro')
plt.text(X[idx]+0.1, Y[idx], "S", horizontalalignment="center")
# ls.cla()

plt.show()
```

[image: Результат работы программы]

Пользуясь вопросом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib пробовал реализовать различные способы:

```
plt.close(ls)
fig.clf()
plt.close(fig)
ls.cla()
```

но никакой из них не дал требуемого результата. Как можно реализовать возможность удаления определённых линий и точек в графике?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего сохранить ссылки не соответствующие объекты и у них вызвать метод remove.

В примере для удаления необходимо нажать любую кнопку.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

line1, = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
line2, = plt.plot([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
path1 = plt.scatter([3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 5])
contour = plt.contour(np.arange(5*5).reshape(5, 5))

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
line1.remove()

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
line2.remove()

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
path1.remove()

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
for collection in contour.collections:
    collection.remove()

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
plt.ioff()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезная информация. Но как можно реализовать подобный метод для контурных графиков, таких как `l1 = b1*x+b1*v - v*y`
`vb = plt.contour(x,y, l1, [0], colors='red')` ?

Comment: @СергейКузнецов обновил пример. С контуром чуть сложнее, так как он набор объектов представляет поэтому удалять нужно в цикле. Зато можно только часть контура удалить в случае необходимости.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Лично для меня данный ответ можно считать максимально подробным.